# c# how to make username appear appear on another web page

Tags: c#, authentication

Hi.  I have a login webpage and a welcome webpage. I have the usernames and passwords saved in a database. After login I redirect to the welcome page. Let's say I login as Dave. I want the welcome page to say Welcome Dave. 
How do I do this?

I tried a bunch of things unsuccessfully - I created a label on the welcome page and tried calling it from the login page but that wasn't allowed. Is there a way I can connect labels from different web pages??
Are there tools in the toolbox that can link pages together?

Or should I focus on doing something with the database?

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you using here. Is it an MVC page? Are you using the built it login systems? Or is it a custom login system? My answer is valid for the built in authentication system, but may not be if you are using something custom!

Answer (score 7):

You need to create `Session` for this purpose.

```
Session["Name"]=txtLoginName.Text;
```

This way you can create and assign value to session.

```
Welcome <%=Session["Name"]%>
```

In this way you can print its value.

ASP.NET Session is explained over [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @user2456977 you can accept this answer by clicking on tickmark besides my answer if its helpful to you :)

Comment: A little more elaboration on this answer would make it really helpful and useful. Where should the "Welcome <%=Session..." be placed though? On the redirected page?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the current users name by using the following:

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

So you would set your label text to that. For example:

```
 lblUsername.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Or you could store that in a Session variable somewhere like this:

```
 Session["Username"] =  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the most correct answer. I do, however, fear that the OP is not using the built-in authentication framework, so I don't know if this will give him the right result.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Yes i was wondering this myself as there wasnt really much detail given. Not sure if its MVC etc. But I am hoping it helps at least

Answer (score 1):

In your page, add something like this:

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblWellcome" CssClass="lblSimple" runat="server" Text="Welcame">      </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserData" CssClass="lblSimple"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>
</table>
```

When the user logs in, store fullname in a Session variable and set the label values through the Session variable

Comment: You are wellcome, although i cannot understand who post -1 and why. Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the value of your username textbox in the session like:

```
Session["Username"] = IdOfYourTextBox.Text;
```

And get this Session at the welcome page.

Answer (score 1):

after login redirect to your welcome page. on that page say your label if named lblUserName, then do this:

```
lblUserName.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Alternatively you can use Session as follows:

on the login page if user is authenticated set

```
Session["UserName"] = YourUserNameTextBox.Text;
```

and then on the welcome page do this

```
lblUserName.Text = Session["UserName"].toString();
```